# How can I open a tag in a component and close in other component

Tags: reactjs

I want to open a tag of Container component (a styled component) in Header Component and close it in Footer component. How can I do it?

Header Component

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  HeaderDefault, Nav, Logo, HeaderFlex, Container,
} from '../../style';

export default () => (
  <>

    <HeaderDefault>
    
    // I want to open tag here
   <Container> 
      <HeaderFlex>
        <Logo>
          <img src="src/assets/img/logo192.png" />
        </Logo>
        <Nav>
          Menu
        </Nav>
      </HeaderFlex>
     </HeaderDefault>

  </>
);
```

Footer Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { FooterDefault, Container } from '../../style';

export default () => (
  <>
    <FooterDefault><h1>footer</h1></FooterDefault>
    
    // and close tag here
    </Container> 
  </>
);
```

Comment: You should create a new component called e.g. Container and then put all of your page components in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your question, JSX tags must match in one file, maybe you should use `Container` in one Component and import `Footer` in this Component,like

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  HeaderDefault, Nav, Logo, HeaderFlex, Container,
} from '../../style';
// import Footer Component from your second file
import Footer from './Footer';

export default () => (
  <>

    <HeaderDefault>
    
    // I want to open tag here
   <Container> 
      <HeaderFlex>
        <Logo>
          <img src="src/assets/img/logo192.png" />
        </Logo>
        <Nav>
          Menu
        </Nav>
      </HeaderFlex>
     </HeaderDefault>

     <Footer />
    </Container>
  </>
);
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { FooterDefault, Container } from '../../style';

export default () => (
  <>
    <FooterDefault><h1>footer</h1></FooterDefault>
  </>
);
```

Comment: I think all tags have to be closed. I can't open it in one component and close it in another.